# How can I create a variable path in Warp?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'm trying to have a variable path in Warp. I have tried this:

```
use uuid::Uuid;
use warp::{self, Filter};

fn main() {
    let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();

    println!("{}", uuid);

    let hello = warp::path(&uuid.to_string()).map(|| "hello world");

    warp::serve(hello).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080));
}
```

but I get the error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:9:29
  |
9 |     let hello = warp::path(&uuid.to_string()).map(|| "hello world");
  |                 ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-                      - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                 |           |
  |                 |           creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |                 argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

What is the best way to have the path parameter have a `'static` lifetime?

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question [in this form](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4fe049fafd738f32bc64a7fd490ebbd7) to let people test your code easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "temporary value dropped while borrowed" when trying to update an Option<&str> in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488127/getting-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-when-trying-to-update-an-option)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a static string from an allocated one by leaking it.

```
let uuid_str = Box::leak(uuid.to_string().into_boxed_str());
let hello = warp::path(uuid_str).map(|| "hello world");
```