# Should I use Option<()> instead of bool, and is there overhead?

Tags: rust

My function might fail, but it doesn't return result, the empty type in rust is `()` as such takes up 0 bytes, if Option is defined like that

```rs
pub enum Option<T> {
    None,
    Some(T),
}
```

It shouldn't have overhead (on return) at all, because the tag only takes up 1 byte, just like the boolean. Is that correct? Upon inspecting Compiler Explorer disassembly output I found out that they produce exactly the same code, but I still wonder if that is correct for all cases, is there cases where returning empty option might have an overhead?

The convenience of `Option<()>` over `bool` is unwrapping and handling functions

Just in case my function that returns empty option will be called a lot.

Comment: I would find something that returned `Option<()>` a bit odd. If something can fail, I'd expect a `Result<(), SomeError>`. `SomeError` can be a unit or empty struct and it'd still be the same as a bool under the hood.

Comment: I believe `Result<(), ()>` fits a little bit better.

Comment: [Null pointer optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557608/what-is-the-null-pointer-optimization-in-rust)